# php How to allow nested default value

Tags: php

```
    level1();

    function level1($value = null){
       level2($value);
    }

    function level2($value = 100){}
```

How can I define $value of level1 as optional and still have the default of level2 applied?

Above code would not use the default because $value is already set to null by level1.

Comment: perhaps not the most elegant - `($value === null)?level2():level2($value);`

Comment: Might be a case where [ParameterObject](https://refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html) can actually be useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the default value to be applied, you have to skip the argument completely. The easiest solution would be just to check, if `$value === null`

```
function level1($value = null){
    if ($value === null) {
       level2();
    } else {
       level2($value);
    }
}
```

If you want to check, if the default value of level1 is applied, you could use `func_num_args()`.

```
 function level1($value = null){
    if (func_num_args() == 0) {
       level2();
    } else {
       level2($value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way of doing it, it supports unlimited arguments:

```
function level1(){
    $args = func_get_args();
    call_user_func_array('level2', $args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always do

`function level2($value){
    if($value === null)
       $value = 100;
}`

It's not the same as what you're looking for, but it has the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps a bit dirty, but should work:

```
<?php

    function level1($value = null){
        ($value === null)?level2():level2($value);
    }

    function level2($value = 100){echo $value;}

    level1();
    level1(7);


?>
```

this prints 100 followed by a 7.